# Getting UnSupportedOperationException when removing keyset values from a map

Tags: java, list, exception, java-8, maps

I have this below piece of method that iterates through a map and removes data based on certain criteria.

```
private Map<String, String> getSearchResultsWithoutOverUsedData(
    Map<String, String> searchDocumentResults
) {
    List<String> overUsedTestData = this.extractOverUsedTestData(
        searchDocumentResults
    );

    if (overUsedTestData.size() > 0) {
        this.deleteSearchResultsAboveThresholdUsage(overUsedTestData);
        searchDocumentResults.keySet().removeAll(overUsedTestData);
    }
    return searchDocumentResults;
}
```

When the line `searchDocumentResults.keySet().removeAll(overUsedTestData);` gets executed, it throws the following error sometimes.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.removeAll(Collections.java:1070) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
    at TestDataHandler.getSearchResultsWithoutOverUsedData(TestDataHandler.java:55) ~[MyService-1.0.jar:?]
```

As the parameter searchDocumentsResults is not final, I'm confused why its immutable. Any help to understand this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `searchDocumentResults` map happens to be immutable, you should create its copy first and then remove the `overUsedTestData`:

```java
searchDocumentResults = new HashMap<>(searchDocumentResults);
searchDocumentResults.keySet().removeAll(overUsedTestData);
```

or using Stream API:

```java
searchDocumentResults = searchDocumentResults.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> !overUsedTestData.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue
        ));
```